# How to check if a page is being loaded for the first time - or hard refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a template that uses an icon library called `material-icons`. And when using a slower internet connection, it shows the icon's code (example below) in plain text until the icon is grabbed from cdn. It lasts less than a second, but still bad for user experience.

Icon code that shows on screen while icon is loading (only the `point_of_sale` part)

```
<i class="material-icons">point_of_sale</i>
```

Therefore I want to add a delay with css to let these icons load first and then fade in with a nice animation, but I don't want it to happen every time the page reloads, so I need to be able to determine if a page is loaded for the first time or reloaded with something like `Ctrl + F5` to be able to add class to these icons to load them slowly.

I'm aware that I can use cookies to determine if it's the first time the page is loaded or not. But it is not very reliable since doing a `Ctrl + F5` can break that control by not deleting the cookies but still hard refreshing the page.

Comment: What about using localStorage instead of cookies?

Comment: JS:

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var firstLoad = sessionStorage.getItem('firstLoad') || localStorage.getItem('firstLoad');
    
      if (!firstLoad) {
        var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('material-icons');
        for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
          icons[i].classList.add('slow-load');
        }
    
        sessionStorage.setItem('firstLoad', true);
      }
    });

Comment: CSS:

    .material-icons {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .slow-load {
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .material-icons:not(.slow-load) {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .material-icons.slow-load {
      opacity: 1;
    }

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, you are likely to create worse UX than just letting the icons load the same way every time (with the fade in). For example, you never know if someone does a hard refresh to disable cache, or if cache is disabled in their browser, or if the user is on a slow connection, or any number of scenarios you can't imagine... and I assure you you cannot imagine all the ways users use your app.

The question I think you should be asking is: How often do users actually reload with `Ctrl + F5`? I doubt it is very often. If you don't know for sure (eg. analytics), then I wouldn't worry about it.

Taking a step back, the primary reason to have the text place-holders is for accessibility (screen readers and such). There are other ways to preserve the accessibility without rendering any visible text as [outlined here](https://a11y-101.com/development/icons-and-links). This way you don't waste your time trying to satisfy some weird UX thing and you preserve accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Users hard refreshing is only one of the problems that _may_ occur in my app. I'm building a business tool and it's for a 3rd world country where internet connection isn't always stable. So I need my app to work (at least look) fine even with bad connections.

I can't use fade in every single page load because when I hard refresh, even on my pc, it can take up to 3 seconds to load the icons. It can be excusable when the page is loaded for the first time but if I add a 3s delay on every page load it'll be a nightmare for the users, might as well not use icons at all

Comment: If you know your users are going to be on a slow connection, you might be best to use inline SVGs for your icons. This might make your HTML a little heavier, but it's less heavy than making a request for a large icon font or similar. Google uses inline SVGs, and they are highly optimized to be very small. Facebook still uses image sprites where they have many icons in a single image and use background-position to show only one icon at a time. The problem with using Material's icons is that you are downloading thousands of icons only to use a dozen or so. It's extremely wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, solution by @IvanSushkov

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var firstLoad = sessionStorage.getItem('firstLoad') || localStorage.getItem('firstLoad');
    if (!firstLoad) {
        var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('material-icons');
        for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
            icons[i].classList.add('slow-load');
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem('firstLoad', true);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.material-icons {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slow-load {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.material-icons:not(.slow-load) {
    opacity: 1;
}

.material-icons.slow-load {
    opacity: 1;
}
```